# Fill combobox with english months

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, globalization

I have to fill a combobox with month in English: January, February, etc.
I did it next way:

```
private string[] AmericanMonths
{
  get
  {
    var arr = new string[12];
    var americanCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
      arr[i] = new DateTime(2000, i + 1, 1).ToString("MMMM", americanCulture);
    }
    return arr;
  }
}

comboMonth.Items.AddRange(AmericanMonths);
```

How do you think, what way is better (perfomance)?

Is there a way to convert an integer representing month number to it's name?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The CultureInfo already contains the list of month names right in the framework. You could just write:

```
var americanCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
comboMonth.Items.AddRange(americanCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames.Take(12)); //to remove last empty element
```

Comment: +1 for the use of a descriptive variable name to make the code 'self-documenting'!

Comment: Thanks! An how do you think, what is the best way to remove last empty item in that array? I found only ToList(); RemoveAt(length - 1); ToArray()

Comment: This should do it: americanCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames.Take(12)

Comment: +1 also for better performing solution.

I did 100000 iterations of original and your solution.

00:02.59 - Original solution
00:02.03 - Jose Basilio's solution.

Answer (score 2):

CultureInfo has [DateTimeFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.datetimeformat.aspx) property which contains the information about the date time formatting. From there you can use [GetMonthName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.getmonthname.aspx) or [GetAbbreviatedMonthName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.getabbreviatedmonthname.aspx). Or alternatively you can get the array of month names through the [MonthNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.monthnames.aspx) property of the DateTimeFormatInfo.